# Gradle file copy not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have the following script in build.gradle of an app project.  All the println lines work fine meaning the task is run. However no files are copied.  I am new to Gradle.  I am probably missing something very simple.  Any tip will be greatly appreciated.

```
assembleRelease.doLast {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
            def releaseBuildTask = tasks.create(name: 'copy', type: Copy) {
                println("Step A")
                from 'build/outputs/apk/'
                println("Step B")
                into 'build/outputs/debug/'
                println("Finished")
            }
            releaseBuildTask.mustRunAfter variant.assemble
        }
    }
    println "copying task finished"
}
```

**Update (2015-01-02)**
I have noticed that I can do other file tasks such as deleting, renaming without any problem, but not copying.

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess you cannot add tasks if you are already in the execution phase of the build. See here: https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

Comment: Does the working of those println() commands indicate the task is actually executed?  I added those println() commands for this purpose?

Comment: No, it just means that the task has been configured, i.e. the from and into directories have been set. It does not mean that the copy was done.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not sure whether I was clear in my previous comment. What I meant by working is that I actually see the outputs of those println() commands in the Run window. I can even use project.files(project.file('build/outputs/apk').listFiles()).each {...} to display the contents of the folder, and I also see the contents of the folder in the Run window.

Comment: Yes, it's clear. Again, the closure that *configures* the copy task (the one containing the print statements) was executed but not the task itself.

Comment: Got you.  Thanks a lot for the clarification. I am still getting a hang of this Gradle thing. The Run windows shows :app:assembleRelease (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 22,5,main]) completed. Took 0.027 secs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68035/discussion-between-hong-and-henry).